# understanding the effect of `alignas` and ubsan

Tags: c, memory-alignment

I'm looking at some legacy code from someone who is no longer the OSS project I work on.  It's a FIFO queue which uses C11 atomics.

Some of the fields in the structures use the alignas keyword, but I'm not entirely sure what the effect is in this case.

The structure definitions are below

```
typedef struct {
    alignas(128) void       *data;
    atomic_int64_t          seq;
} fr_atomic_queue_entry_t;

struct fr_atomic_queue_s {
    alignas(128) atomic_int64_t head;
    atomic_int64_t          tail;

    size_t              size;

    fr_atomic_queue_entry_t     *entry;
};
```

Firstly i'm trying to figure out the real world effect on the `alignas` keyword.

Starting at the top in `fr_atomic_queue_entry_t`, `alignas` is added to the definition of the `data` field.  Does this mean padding is inserted between `data`/`seq`.

In `fr_atomic_queue_s` `alignas` is applied to the head field, which presumably holds the insertion index of the fifo. Does this mean padding is inserted between `head`/`tail`?

Secondly, what's the point of 128 byte alignment, is it something to do with the integrity of the atomic operations, or cache alignment?

The full code is available here: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/master/src/lib/io/atomic_queue.c

I don't expect a definitive answer, just wondering if anyone has any clues.

Lastly, and the reason why I'm examining the code.  We recently enabled LLVM's UBSAN, and it's failing with the following:

```
src/lib/io/atomic_queue.c:85:7: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0x00010a16f860 for type 'fr_atomic_queue_t' (aka 'struct fr_atomic_queue_s'), which requires 128 byte alignment
0x00010a16f860: note: pointer points here
 be be be be  be be be be be be be be  be be be be be be be be  be be be be be be be be  be be be be
```

What is that error actually saying needs to change? `fr_atomic_queue_s` is heap allocated, does the start of the struct need to be 128 byte aligned?

Should the size of `fr_atomic_queue_entry_t` be a multiple of 128? Does the start of the array which holds to entries need to be aligned to 128 bytes?

Comment: "128bit alignment on a 64bit" - you mean 128 _byte_?

Comment: I do indeed.  As it was 128 I figured it was bits, but reading the docs, and ubsan output, you're quite correct it's bytes... Now I'm really confused.

Comment: It is most likely aligned to avoid memory (cache) access interference. The code you linked allocates memory using `talloc_size` for a structure with 128 byte alignment. So this is clearly wrong (or we can say just pointless). There was no point in aligning the structure when allocation must be aligned instead.

Comment: That's what I figured.  We have an internal function which will hand back talloc chunks of a specific alignment so I can switch to that.

If this is to avoid cache access interference would it also be useful to have `head` and `tail` in different cache lines, as the producer and consumer will likely be executing on different CPU cores?

Comment: If this removes interference - then yes, this will improve performance and is commonly done for such data structures. But make sure to separate everything properly - shared data should not be in the same cache line at `head` or `tail`: if you just add `alignas`, it will share the cache line with `tail` - you need padding for this.